# Insert a subreport dynamically in main Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am making a report in SAP Crystal Reports. I made couple of header and footer "templates" which I need to switch in via C# code. Here is the thing, in my main report, I inserted one header and one footer report which are there by default and depending on parameter I need to switch them with some external "template" which is somewhere on the disc.

I know how to access the subreport via code and to change the values of the objects, but I don't know how to switch them:

```
ReportDocument mainReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
ReportDocument subReportHeader = mainReportDocument .Subreports["Header.rpt"];
....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the goal of separate header and footer files?  What are you trying to achieve?  Different logos?  Client names?

Comment: Yes, excaly that. Different styles, different clients etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the RAS SDK's [SubreportControllerClass.ImportSubreport Method](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2sp2/en/en/RAS_SDK/rassdk_net_doc/doc/rassdk_net_doc/html/raslrfCrystalDecisionsReportAppServerControllersSubreportControllerClassImportSubreportTopic.htm) or the [ImportSubreportEx Method](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RAS_SDK/rassdk_net_doc/doc/rassdk_net_doc/html/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers~CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.SubreportControllerClass~ImportSubreportEx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ReportDocument mainReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
ReportDocument subReportHeader = mainReportDocument .Subreports["Header.rpt"];
```